# Ping in C# returns null when not first method

Tags: c#

I'm obviously new to C# and have some experience with Powershell, but this one has me stumped.

I need to create a method that pings a host, and if it receives a reply, send out some Telnet commands to it, but I'm stuck on the ping reply.

If I create the method and put it as the only method in the namespace, or at least the main method, it behaves as expected and returns the expected result.

*This Works:*

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace VIMS_Pull_System
{
    class PingTruck
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            string IPAddress = "127.0.0.1";
            int timeout = 7;
            string PingStatus;
            try
            {   Ping Truck = new Ping();
                PingReply reply = Truck.Send(IPAddress, timeout);

                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    PingStatus = "Found Truck";
                else
                    PingStatus = "Can't Find Truck";
             }
            catch (PingException)
            {
                PingStatus = "No Truck";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(PingStatus);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as I want to add other methods to the same namespace, the ping returns a "null" value.

*This Does Not Work*

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace VIMS_Pull_System
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        //I'm thinking the below should run the PingTruck method and set the variable PingStatus,
        //then write it's status to the console, but it returns a null value.
        {   new PingTruck();      
            Console.WriteLine(PingTruck.PingStatus);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class PingTruck
    {
        public static string PingStatus;
        public static string Main(String[] args)
        {
            string IPAddress = "127.0.0.1";
            int timeout = 7;

            try
            {   Ping Truck = new Ping();
                PingReply reply = Truck.Send(IPAddress, timeout);

                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    return PingStatus = "Found Truck";
                else
                    return PingStatus = "Can't Find Truck";
            }
            catch (PingException)
            {
                return PingStatus = "No Truck";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something easy, if anybody can explain why it returns null when not the main menu, I's appreciate the help! Thanks for your patience with the new guy!

Comment: You never actually use PingTruck... PingTruck.Main(ArbitraryStringArrayHere) would fill the PingStatus property...

Answer (score 2):

In your second example, you have two classes that both have a static function called Main().

The lines (from the second version)

```
new PingTruck();      
Console.WriteLine(PingTruck.PingStatus);
```

create an instance of PingTruck, but do not assign that instance to anything, then check a static property of the class PingTruck called PingStatus. At no point to you run the code in PingTruck.Main()

The minimal-effort solution is to replace

```
new PingTruck();
```

with

```
PingTruck.Main();
```

However, it would be better to change the static things in PingTruck to be instance things (Main(), but call it something else like DoPing(), and PingStatus). Then, do something like this in your Program.Main()

```
var truck = new PingTruck();      
truck.DoPing();
Console.WriteLine(truck.PingStatus);
```

Answer (score 1):

You create an instance of your object (though you never do anything with it):

```
new PingTruck()
```

But you never actually *invoke the method* that does anything.  Instead, you just immediately check the status:

```
Console.WriteLine(PingTruck.PingStatus)
```

Since the logic was never invoked, the status was never set to anything.  So it's the default value of `null`.

Simply invoke the method:

```
PingTruck.Main(args);
Console.WriteLine(PingTruck.PingStatus);
```

Note also that an instance of the object wasn't required, because the method and status value are both `static`.

---

Note also that this code has a few things which don't necessarily make sense.  While it may "work", it could certainly be cleaned up and clarified.

For example, your `PingTruck` class doesn't need everything to be static.  If you remove the `static` modifiers, then you'd use the members on an instance:

```
var truck = new PingTruck();
truck.Main(args);
Console.WriteLine(truck.PingStatus);
```

Additionally, your `PingTruck.Main()` method should *probably* be named something else.  Maybe something like `Ping()`?  `Main` doesn't really describe what the method actually *does*.

That method also doesn't seem to need that `args` parameter, since it never uses it.

(You seem to be under the impression that *all* methods in an application need to be named `Main(string[] args)` and need to be `static`.  I assure you, that's not the case at all.)

It also doesn't make much sense to both set a public property *and* return the value.  Why not *just* return the value?  For example:

```
return "Found Truck";
```

Then in the consuming code:

```
var truck = new PingTruck();
Console.WriteLine(truck.Ping());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of the PingTruck class

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    //I'm thinking the below should run the PingTruck method and set the variable PingStatus,
    //then write it's status to the console, but it returns a null value.
    {   
        pingTruck =  new PingTruck();      
        Console.WriteLine(pingTruck.PingMethod);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The static `Main` method is for your console class.  To use another class for this just use another public class

```
public class PingTruck
{
    public string PingStatus;
    public string PingMethod()
    {
        string IPAddress = "127.0.0.1";
        int timeout = 7;

        try
        {   Ping Truck = new Ping();
            PingReply reply = Truck.Send(IPAddress, timeout);

            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                return PingStatus = "Found Truck";
            else
                return PingStatus = "Can't Find Truck";
        }
        catch (PingException)
        {
            return PingStatus = "No Truck";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your `PingTruck.Main(String[] args)` method is called?

Why are you creating an instance of `PingTruck` if it has only `Static` members?

The simpliest solution is:

```
PingTruck.Main(args);
Console.WriteLine(PingTruck.PingStatus);
Console.ReadLine();
```

But, I highly recommend that you review your code design.